# Is is possible to identify when processing the last line in an io.readlines iteration

Tags: python, python-3.x

Consider the following:

```
from typing import Callable

def execShellCmd(self, dataLineReceiver: Callable = None):
    try:
        p = subprocess.Popen(
            shlex.split(self._cmd),
            shell=False,
            stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
            stderr=subprocess.STDOUT,
            env=None,
            bufsize=0,
            cwd=self.cwd,
            text=True
        )
        while p.poll() is None:
            line = p.stdout.readline()
            self.parseLine(line, p.returncode, dataLineReceiver)
            
        for line in p.stdout.readlines():
            self.parseLine(line, p.returncode, dataLineReceiver)
            
        p.stdout.close()
        
        return p.returncode
    except Exception as ex:
        print("Exception: {}".format(ex))
    return -1
```

I pass each line read from `stdout` to the `parseLine` function and then onto the passed in function/method `dataLineReceiver`.
I would like to indicate to the data receiver when it is getting the last line so it, knows no more data lines are coming and can do other things.

I.e. change the following code to get a bool, or some other indicator:

```
for line in p.stdout.readlines():
    self.parseLine(line, p.returncode, dataLineReceiver, lastlinebool)
```

where `lastlinebool` would be True or False depending if the last line before EOF had been reached.

Comment: Why can't the data receiver start doing other things *after* it has received the last line?

Comment: It can once it knows it has had the last line.  Hence my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using `readlines()` you receive a list of lines and by taking its length you will know which iteration is the last one if you keep track of a count.

```
stdout_lines = p.stdout.readlines()
num_lines = len(stdout_lines)

for i, line in enumerate(stdout_lines):
    lastlinebool = (i == num_lines - 1)
    self.parseLine(line, p.returncode, dataLineReceiver, lastlinebool)
```

Comment: Hmm, this would certainly work, providing the p.poll while loop didn't actually have and pass the last line, thus, readlines had no lines at all.  I hadn't thought that through until I saw this suggestion from @mkrieger1